# Self solder 8-pin din cable

Tags: signal-integrity, shielding

a bit of specific question. I want to build my own cable based on pins stated in the manual of an old camera, so I can capture the video (composite video) and audio signal.

**Question:** Is there something I should do to mitigate possible signal interference, when choosing the wires of the cable, even thogh there are already pins reserved for the shielding?

Recently I bought a analog camera, which has a 8 pin din connection. This combines the output for the video and and power supply for the camera. To display the camera output, I have other devices that work with composite video input. So for this to work, I want to build a cable with 8-pin din connector on the camera side and analog video and 12 v (6.5W) power supply on the display side. I know all the pins of the 8-pin camera side, they are stated in the manual. *There are also explicitly pins reserved for shielding.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the composite video, you need coaxial cable with characteristic impedance of 75 ohms. The shield of the coaxial cable should be enough to protect the signal from disturbances. The coaxial shield should be connected to the video signal ground pin, if there is a separate ground pin for video.

For the power supply, it is usually enough to use the cable you see on standard wall warts.